# How to change the default value of Cassandra counter

Tags: cassandra, cql

In Cassandra counter, if I try to increase counter in none existing row , it creates the row set the value to zero and then increase the value as requested.

My question is can I change the default value not to be zero but something else. for example: previous bucket or something similar (row2 = row1+value)

Answer (score 5):

You can't set the value of a counter only increment or decrement.

> A counter column value is a 64-bit signed integer. You cannot set the
>   value of a counter, which supports two operations: increment and
>   decrement.

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/counter_type.html

Comment: Do you have an idea how to implement my requested feature?

Answer (score 2):

You can set initial value for counter like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE counters (
      counter_name text,
      counter_value counter,
      PRIMARY KEY (counter_name)
    );

    UPDATE counters SET counter_value = counter_value + 100500 WHERE counter_name='FooCounter';
    SELECT * from counters;

     counter_name | counter_value
    --------------+---------------
       FooCounter |        100500
```

After that use counter as you need:

```
    UPDATE counters SET counter_value = counter_value + 1 WHERE counter_name='FooCounter';
    SELECT * from counters;

     counter_name | counter_value
    --------------+---------------
       FooCounter |        100501
```